# Two squares are chosen at random on a chessboard. What is the probability that they have a side in common?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

Two squares are chosen at random on a chessboard. What is the probability that they have a side in common?
I have got the total no of events by using 64 C 2. But I am unable to find the numerator(no. of favorable events).

Comment: The numerator is simply the number of sides. There are $8$ sides on every vertical line dividing columns, $8$ sides on every horizontal one dividing rows. Now, these lines are $7+7=14$, hence the numerator is $8 \cdot 14$.

Comment: Hint: there are three different kinds of squares on a chessboard: those at the corner, those along a side (but not at a corner) and the rest.

Comment: Hint: Every row has 7 ways of arranging two squares with a common side. And every column has 7 ways of arranging two squares with a common side as well.

Comment: You must count the pairs $(a,b)$ of squares such that $b$ is either below or on the right of $a$. Then, use almagest's idea.

Comment: For the visualization, it is more convenient to think in terms of first chosen square and second chosen square. So a sample space of $(64)(63)$ may be more convenient for the calculation.

Comment: You can just count the number of edges that are shared by two squares.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may count the couples of adjacent squares in the following way: for any square, we may consider how many adjacent squares there are, sum everything, divide by two:
$$ \frac{4\cdot 2+ 24\cdot 3+36\cdot 4}{2}=112. $$
The couples of squares are $\binom{64}{2}=2016$, hence the wanted probability is
$$ \frac{112}{2016}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{18}}.$$

Comment: +1.  I would have said there are $8 \times 7 \times 2=112$ internal (i.e. shared) edges

Comment: @Henry: that is another perfectly sound way.

Comment: Why did we divide the numerator by 2?

Comment: @MAthsjunky The sample space $\binom{64}{2}$ is unorderred, i.e. $(A,B)$ is the same as $(B,A)$ where $A$ & $B$ are different squares. However, the formula in the numerator counts _ordered_ pairs ($(A,B)$ is different from $(B,A)$) so it double-counts. To counteract that, divide by two.
---
You could also change the sample space to be ordered, so $64*63=4032$, and then do $\frac{224}{4032}$ which is the same.

Comment: @Henry Would you kindly elaborate on how you reached 8*7*2?

Comment: @Macindows: both the horizontal and the vertical internal edges are $7\cdot 8$.